# Error ORA-03111 break received on communication channel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, oracle10g

I've got error ORA-03111 Break received on communication channel after change from oracle 11g to oracle 10g R1 at different server.

I use DotNet framework 4.5.

I have google around but didnt find any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case (getting the exception on `connection.Open()`) the problem turned out to be that the Oracle server was too old a version to use the Managed Provider.

According to: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2528641

> ODP.NET, Managed Driver supports connecting to Oracle DB server 10.2
>   or higher. It does not support DB 10.1.

Comment: I think the same thing too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the reason was that input to the NVL function returned more than one row - the blabla subquery in the following:

```
PROCEDURE my_procedure(c_my_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
  p_my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN p_my_cursor FOR
  select nvl((select blabla), 0) my_column from my_table;
  c_my_cursor := p_my_cursor;
END smiley_alle_jurenheder;
```

Interestingly enough, when running the query directly in SQL Developer, the correct error code is returned - "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row".

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the first Google hit when searching for this error, guess I'll add my solution as well. This error seems to crop up for all sorts of reasons which makes it really hard to troubleshoot.

I ran into it while building an application which runs on both MSSQL and Oracle. Upon startup it creates a simple table. To prevent errors, any existing table is dropped. This multi-line, multi-command script runs fine on MSSQL but its Oracle equivalent kept returning this error.

I finally solved it when I ran the commands (drop, create table, create sequence) one by one. Also, look out for the semicolon (;) as leaving that in a DDL statement also gave the ORA-03111 error.

In retrospect, I knew that running multiple commands in one go was troublesome in Oracle, but this error is just plain useless to those not initated in Oracle's arcane ways.

Comment: you are not giving a solution to the problem just elaborated the theory of something.

Comment: Upvote for the semicolon(;) that was my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was a missing column on the database. It was created in another environment.
It was hard to find the real problem cause this error dont tell us nothing.

While debugging in other computer, the real problem appeared.

Hope this help someone.

Comment: Similiar cause while I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, my case is a typo in column name.

Answer (score 0):

I have yet another cause.  I'm querying PeopleSoft and if I make an integer filter where a string is expected I get this.

This will fail with ORA-03111:

```
SELECT Q.* FROM sysadm.PS_WMV_PRC_DISTRIB Q WHERE 1=1 AND PROJECT_ID = 123
```

While this is fine:

```
SELECT Q.* FROM sysadm.PS_WMV_PRC_DISTRIB Q WHERE 1=1 AND PROJECT_ID = '123'
```

So many uses for this one message!  I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was with the name of the table column, which I had created with double quotes(") because it was one of Oracle's reserved words, but NHibernate did not understand this and sent it without double quotes when sending the command.
I changed the column name to an unreserved word.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have yet another cause as well.  I'm querying an Oracle database version 19.18.0.0.0 but I have also seen this with other earlier versions, and the issue was not necessarily with Oracle but with the .net data types.  Specifically, it has to do with the conversion from Oracle data types to those supported by the .net framework.  For example Oracle's float (or NUMBER) data type can represent more decimals than the corresponding .net data types, so when a value is received that cannot be converted to a corresponding .net data type, you get a "break received on communications channel" error.  To reproduce this effect, simply execute a query similar to this

```
select foo from bar
```

where foo is a field with a data type of NUMBER and a value such as 1/3.

One resolution to this issue is to simply round the number to however many decimal points you require (within the limits of the .net data type) such as

```
select round(foo, 2) from bar
```

Be sure to understand the data that your are retrieving from the database so that your rounding of the numbers makes sense and doesn't truncate too much information.